# Can I assign a combination of variables using one "with" template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the template code `value="{{ key|slice:":4" }}-{{ suggestion.pk }}"` which slices the variable `key`, appends a "-" and the value of `suggestion.pk`. I now want to assign this combined value to the name `id` using the built-in `with` template tag.

Is there a way to do this using one `with` tag or do I have to use a custom template tag?

Using

```
{% with id={{ key|slice:":4" }}-{{ suggestion.pk }} %}
{{ id }}                    
{% endwith %}
```

doesn't work and throws the error `Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'`. I also tried doing something like

```
{% with id= key|slice:":4"-suggestion.pk %}
{{ id }}                    
{% endwith %}
```

or adding some extra quotes, which also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
{% with sliced_key=key|slice:":4" suggestion_pk=suggestion.pk id=sliced_key|add:'-'|add:suggestion_pk %}
{{ id }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I tried `{% with sliced_key=key|slice:":4" id=sliced_key|add:'-'|add:suggestion.pk %}` and it rendered the dash and `suggestion.pk` correctly but the sliced_key value was missing from the result. And if I copy paste your answer including setting `suggestion_pk` (which shouldn't be necessary) it throws a weird error.